# Car won't start. No noise. All electrical seems to work fine.

Tags: ford, starting, taurus

Here's what I have done so far:

Replaced the battery (it was dead)
Replaced the battery cables (they were super old)
Replaced the starter relay

For a while, the car would start intermittently.  If I waited a couple of days, it would start up no problem. Now, it won't start at all.

2002 Ford Taurus SES.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is the battery dead again?

Answer (score 1):

Put a multimeter on the leads running to the starter solenoid, and see if it's getting power when you have the key turned to "start". If it does, you need a new starter. If it doesn't, you have an problem between the ignition and the starter. BTW - the "previously intermittent start problem" is a classic "starter solenoid going bad" symptom.